# If all input fields are dirty return true, How?

Tags: jquery

If **all** fields in the form are dirty return true if not then return false.
Here is my code.

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = false;

    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") && this.defaultValue != this.value) {
            hasChanges = true;
            return false;             }
        else {
            if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") && this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                hasChanges = true;
                return false;                 }
            else {
                if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                        if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                            hasChanges = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return hasChanges;
}
```

I used this code and tried to manipulate it but I couldn't figure it out.

**My question is:** How to check if all fields on the form are dirty?

Comment: what exactly is your question

Comment: what does "dirty" means exactly?

Comment: Dirty means that it has value and it's not the defaultValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong i think. You are returning false everywhere so the output will be always false irrespective of whether it has a change or not. Even if you have `hasChanges = true;` you are returning `false` Change your code:

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = false;

    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") && this.defaultValue != this.value) {
            hasChanges = true;
         }
        else 
         {
            if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") && this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                hasChanges = true;
             }
            else 
            {
                if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                        if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                            hasChanges = true;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return hasChanges;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Even the above code will have problem; because once we set it to true, even if the fields in the below query are not changed we are not setting it to false. You need to use this one:

```
function getHasChanges() {
            var hasChanges = false;

            $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
                if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden")) {
                    if(this.defaultValue != this.value) {
                        hasChanges = true;
                    } else {
                        hasChanges = false;
                    }
                    return hasChanges;
                 } else {
                    if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox")) {
                        if(this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                            hasChanges = true;
                        } else {
                            hasChanges = false;
                        }
                     }
                     return hasChanges;
                    else 
                    {
                        if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
                            for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                                if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                                    hasChanges = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return hasChanges;
                    }
                }
            });

            return hasChanges;
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Missed a bracket. Please check this:

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = false;
    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden")) {
            if(this.defaultValue != this.value) {
                hasChanges = true;
            } else {
                hasChanges = false;
            }
            return hasChanges;
         } else if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox")) {
                if(this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                    hasChanges = true;
                } else {
                    hasChanges = false;
                }
             return hasChanges;
         } else if (this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple") {
                for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                    if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                        hasChanges = true;
                    }
                }
                return hasChanges;
         }
    });
    return hasChanges;
}
```

Comment: The code almost works, exepct that if I select a value for a dropdownlist then I return it back to the default value, it gives me true. In other meaning, it the code feels the change from default to a certain value but not the opposite.

Comment: I'll consider this answer is accepted but please @Sabari check the syntax error, in case if someone will use this code.
Thank you

Comment: Sorry missed a bracket earlier. Was tired. Updated the new one. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

As you want to know if **all** fields have changed, I'd reverse the logic.  Initialize hasChanges to true, and set to false as soon as one *doesn't* have a change.

Like this:

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = true;

    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") && this.defaultValue == this.value) {
            hasChanges = false;
        }
        else if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") && this.defaultChecked == this.checked) {
            hasChanges = false;
        }
        else if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                if (this.options[x].selected == this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                    hasChanges = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return hasChanges;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't do, unless the defaultXXX properties don't return what you think... can't say I've ever used them so I'm not sure. Ahh, just spotted a bug on the 'select' part too, so I've updated that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab:

Will return `false` if all fields have a non-default, non-empty-string value. If all fields are either set to their defaults or are empty strings, returns true.

Note: Not tested even for syntax errors, so YMMV.

**EDIT**: Updated: syntax checked, runs now.

**EDIT 2**: Updated again to account for select boxes more intelligently. It's not clear how multi selects *should* be handled, but the way you had it originally is surely giving unexpected results.

For reference, [my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oyuguc) for this.

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var incomplete = false;

    var ch = {
      text: {
            list: ['text', 'textarea', 'hidden'],
            defaultProp: 'defaultValue',
            valueProp: 'value'
        },
      check: {
            list: ['radio', 'checkbox'],
            defaultProp: 'defaultChecked',
            valueProp: 'checked'
        },
      select: {
            list: ['select-one', 'select-multiple'],
            defaultProp: 'defaultSelected',
            valueProp: 'selected',
            multi: 'options'
        }
    };

    $(':input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])').each(function () {
        for(kind in ch){
            for(k in ch[kind].list){
                var type = ch[kind].list[k];
                if(this.type == type){
                    if(ch[kind].multi){
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                            if(type == 'select-one'){
                                // for single select the default needs to have changed 
                                if(this[ch[kind].multi][i][ch[kind].defaultProp] && this[ch[kind].multi][i][ch[kind].valueProp]){
                                    // this defaulted to selected and is still selected
                                    incomplete = true;
                                    return;
                                }
                            } else if(type == 'select-multiple'){
                                // it's not clear what's correct here.
                                // do you want each selected item to change?
                                // for now do nothing.
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(this[ch[kind].valueProp] === '' || this[ch[kind].defaultProp] == this[ch[kind].valueProp]){
                            incomplete = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return incomplete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set `hasChanges = true` and then `return false`.

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = false;

    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") && this.defaultValue != this.value) {
            hasChanges = true;
        else {
            if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") && this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                hasChanges = true;
            else {
                if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                        if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                            hasChanges = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return hasChanges;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. The original `return false` you were seeing was only returning from the anonymous `function(){}`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the "each" at first - thanks for pointing that out.